# How to use ng-init to select a default value in a select box when the ng-model and the ng-options are referencing different objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I have a select box that iterates over `listOfThings`, and the model has a `currentThing` property. The select box binds to `currentThing` correctly.

However, I can't get the `ng-init` to set the default value in `listOfThings` to `currentThing`. The following isn't setting the default value.

```
 <select ng-options = "someThing as someThing.name for someThing in controller.listOfThings"
                                ng-model = "controller.currentThing"
                                ng-init = "someThing = controller.currentThing"
                                ng-change = "controller.changeThing(controller.currentThing)"/>
```

I output the values of `someThing` and `currentThing` and they're the same.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle for same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using in *DOM* you should assign default value in your *controller*

like:

```
$scopr.controller.currentThing = $scopr.controller.listOfThings[0];// first element or as your need
```

and then no need

```
ng-init = "someThing = controller.currentThing"
```